# C++ Partial template specialization confusion

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <typename A, typename B=bool>
struct pair {
    pair() {std::cout<<"This";}
    A first;
    B second;
};

template <typename T>
struct pair<T, bool> {
    pair() {std::cout<<"That";}
    T first;
    bool second;
};
```

I wanted to see, for learning purposes, which of the above structs will be instantiated (the generic declaration or the partial specialization), given the following code:

```
int main() {
    pair<int,int> pairB; // prints 'This'
    pair<double,bool> pairC; // prints 'That'
    pair<float> pairD; // prints 'That'
}
```

While the first two make sense to me, the third... not so much.
Shouldn't the third be 'This' too?
Isn't the second declaration a partial specialization for where the second type is `bool`?
Well... the second type isn't `bool`, so why won't it instantiate the first?

Comment: Well, the second type *is* `bool`, because of your default argument.

Comment: :D :D !!! OK... I didn't think the compiler will go through all that trouble of 'changing its decision' after already going with the first...

Comment: The compiler needs to 'decide' which of these two it needs to instantiate.

Comment: It didn't "already go with the first", so there was nothing to change.

Comment: doesn't the compiler need do 'decide' which of the two to instantiate? how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler sees `pair<float>`, it looks first for the definition of the primary template, which is :

```
template <typename A, typename B=bool>
struct pair
```

This gives the following arguments list (since the second default to `bool`) : `<float, bool>`.

The compiler then looks for any possible matching specialization, and finds one :

```
template <typename T>
struct pair<T, bool>  // Match <float, bool>
```

So this specialization is selected.